# Periodic compaction vs CompactRange

Tags: rocksdb

We do frequent bulk deletion + reloading of data in RocksDB. To ensure that the deleted data does not keep occupying disk space, I set the `periodic_compaction_seconds` to 1 day. This causes RocksDB to reclaim some disk space, but however the overall disk space used continues to grow gradually unless I do a full compaction by calling `CompactRange(rocksdb::CompactRangeOptions(), nullptr, nullptr)`.

Can someone explain to me why the periodic compaction is not doing a good job of purging deleted data from disk?

Here's what the compaction stats look like before and after the `CompactRange()` call:

```
BEFORE

** Compaction Stats [default] **
Level    Files   Size     Score Read(GB)  Rn(GB) Rnp1(GB) Write(GB) Wnew(GB) Moved(GB) W-Amp Rd(MB/s) Wr(MB/s) Comp(sec) CompMergeCPU(sec) Comp(cnt) Avg(sec) KeyIn KeyDrop Rblob(GB) Wblob(GB)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  L0      0/0    0.00 KB   0.0     19.2     0.0     19.2      28.4      9.2       0.0   3.1     34.0     50.3    577.53             57.75      3147    0.184     15M    12K       0.0       0.0
  L1     12/0   416.42 MB   0.8     30.2     9.2     21.0      28.1      7.1       0.0   3.1     75.9     70.5    407.60             69.19        25   16.304     41M   186K       0.0       0.0
  L2    157/0    3.33 GB   0.7      9.8     7.0      2.8       4.2      1.4       0.0   0.6     24.3     10.3    415.53            181.80        32   12.985     20M   529K       0.0       0.0
  L3    721/0   38.24 GB   0.8      1.8     1.8      0.0       1.8      1.8       0.0   1.0     21.5     21.5     87.76             84.15         1   87.762     11M     24       0.0       0.0
  L4    120/0    7.52 GB   0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0       0.0      0.0       0.0   0.0      0.0      0.0      0.00              0.00         0    0.000       0      0       0.0       0.0
 Sum   1010/0   49.50 GB   0.0     61.0    18.1     43.0      62.5     19.5       0.0   6.8     42.0     43.0   1488.42            392.89      3205    0.464     89M   728K       0.0       0.0
 Int      0/0    0.00 KB   0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0       0.0      0.0       0.0   0.0      0.0      0.0      0.00              0.00         0    0.000       0      0       0.0       0.0



AFTER

** Compaction Stats [default] **
Level    Files   Size     Score Read(GB)  Rn(GB) Rnp1(GB) Write(GB) Wnew(GB) Moved(GB) W-Amp Rd(MB/s) Wr(MB/s) Comp(sec) CompMergeCPU(sec) Comp(cnt) Avg(sec) KeyIn KeyDrop Rblob(GB) Wblob(GB)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  L0      1/0    1.04 KB   0.5     19.2     0.0     19.2      28.4      9.2       0.0   3.1     34.0     50.3    577.54             57.75      3149    0.183     15M    12K       0.0       0.0
  L1      0/0    0.00 KB   0.0     30.2     9.2     21.0      28.1      7.1       0.0   3.1     75.9     70.5    407.60             69.19        26   15.677     41M   187K       0.0       0.0
  L2      0/0    0.00 KB   0.0     13.6     7.5      6.1       6.5      0.3       0.0   0.9     25.8     12.3    537.90            297.89        35   15.369     39M  9389K       0.0       0.0
  L3      0/0    0.00 KB   0.0     42.5     4.1     38.4      10.2    -28.3       0.0   2.5     47.7     11.4    913.29            884.19         9  101.477    221M   165M       0.0       0.0
  L4    130/0    8.03 GB   0.0     13.9     6.3      7.6       6.3     -1.3       1.8   1.0     35.4     16.0    403.91            389.24         2  201.953     79M    40M       0.0       0.0
 Sum    131/0    8.03 GB   0.0    119.4    27.1     92.3      79.4    -13.0       1.8   8.6     43.1     28.6   2840.24           1698.25      3221    0.882    397M   215M       0.0       0.0
 Int      0/0    0.00 KB   0.0     23.9     6.8     17.2       8.2     -9.0       1.8 8235570.7     40.8     13.9    600.84            579.93         6  100.140    125M    82M       0.0       0.0
```

I'm using the default RocksDB configuration values.

Answer (score 0):

The `periodic_compaction_seconds` configuration only compacts files to the same level. This is a bit unexpected and there is an attempt to fix this behavior: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/12165